# how can I access to a specific json value in my returned data

Tags: javascript, json

I send a http GET request which returns JSON data in the following form. I am finding it impossible to access this data despite having no problems with example json that I create. I want to ideally take the array under wifi, and use this data to create a html table, but I think I can work out how to create the table if I could just access the actual elements of the data.

I have tried multiple methods to try and reach the first timestamp. I have tried:

```
var element = result.undefined.clients.wifi[0].timestamp;
```

but this returns an error that 'clients' can't be found.

I also tried:

```
var element = result.clients.wifi[0].timestamp; //and
var element = result.wifi[0].timestamp;
```

The JSON data returned to a variable is shown below:

> result = undefined
>   {"sourceId":"idid","sourceType":"CLOUD_source","searchMeta":{"maxResults":4,"metricType":["clients"],"family":["wifi"],"Interval":"M1"},
>   "clients":{"wifi":
>   [{"timestamp":1424716920,"avg":3,"min":1,"max":4,"Count":8,"sCount":3,"sources":["x1","x2","x3","x4","x5","x6","x7","x8"]},{"timestamp":1424716980,"avg":2,"min":1,"max":3,"Count":4,"sCount":2,"sources":["x3","x4","x8","x4"]},{"timestamp":1424717160,"avg":2,"min":1,"max":3,"Count":9,"sCount":4,"sources":["x3","x4"]}]}}

Comment: What's the "undefined" bit starting the JSON data? You seem not to be bothered by it.

Comment: result = undefined? from where did you copied that code? is that returned from server .. or...?

Comment: It is returned from a REST API  server, I am not really familiar with json and since i get all of the data I am interested I didn't realize it was abnormal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON data is invalid. If it is returned from a server, you need to go there and correct the data source, (if you have access to that).

Otherwise, perhaps notify the backend guy(s) about it.

If it is from a REST API, and you are "sure" that the server code should be error free, then check that you have supplied all the required parameters in the API request you are making.

Comment: I do not have access to the server as this as from another company altogether. What should I tell them specifically that the undefined section needs definition.  I have previously used php json_decode and can then access the data as I want, maybe I should use php json_encode to make my own json format instead?

Comment: The http GET request you're sending, how about mailing that code to the support team? Otherwise, check the API documentation of the server, if there is one. Its likely that you did not supply, or properly supply one or more parameters required on the query string.

Comment: Okay thank you guys, I will get in touch with them and ask them for advice on getting the data. There is quite extensive API documentation and I am confident I am adhering to it strictly (I am running their exact example request).

Comment: Okay. Best of luck, then.

Comment: Thanks, I will report back with my solution if I think it could be of any interest to others.

Answer (score 0):

I think your JSON is messed up. I ran it through JSONLint, and having the undefined at the beginning causes things to break.